# set row height for all rows using phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Default row height in excel is -1 which show 15 in excel.This row height automatically resize to 15.75 after add content.So, I set new default row height,15 for all rows. Still, row height getting auto resize. Then, I try to set row height for all rows from `$sheet->getRowDimensions()`. There is no content in `$sheet->getRowDimensions()`. So, `$rd->setRowHeight(15)` does not take effect.

```
$default_rowdimensions  =$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension();
$set_newdefaultrowheight=$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(15);
```

```
$rowdimension = $sheet->getRowDimensions();
echo '<pre>;
var_dump($rowdimension);
echo '</pre>';
foreach($rowdimension  as $rd) 
{ 
    $rd->setRowHeight(15); 
}
```

Is there any other ways to set row height for all rows before write to excel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't this line `$set_newdefaultrowheight=$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(15);` be `$set_newdefaultrowheight=$sheet->setRowHeight(15);`?

Comment: no, `$set_newdefaultrowheight=$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(15);`is the proper code to set default row height.

Answer (score 5):

For PhpSpreadSheet, the correct way to archive this is :

```php
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('2')->setRowHeight(26);
```

Where 2 is the number of row and 26 is the height.

Answer (score 3):

Set the default row height with:

```
$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(15);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to change only for one row?

Comment: Looks like this works:  $sheet->getRowDimension('10')->setRowHeight(15);

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Brother.

```
    // Assuming you have 50 rows or 100 rows above to format
    $a = 50; 
    for($i = 0; $i<$a;$i++){
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setRowHeight(14.25);   
    }
    you can use this as shown above my $a variable assigned 50 rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

here try this.
it will make every used cell (cell with value in it) height to 15.

```
sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $sheet->getRowDimension($row->getRowIndex())->setRowHeight(15);
        }
```